# Azure Functions v2: Filter out dependency tracking

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

Does anyone have some sample code for **Azure Functions V2** to **disable Dependency tracking** via the **host.json**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In host.json, set the field `enableDependencyTracking` to `false`.

For more details, please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#sample-hostjson-file) -> logging field -> applicationInsights field.

A sample of host.json to disable dependency tracking:

```
 {
      "logging": {
        "applicationInsights": {
          "samplingSettings": {
            //other settings
          },
          "enableDependencyTracking": false
        }
      }
    }
```

And the screenshot of sample from the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#sample-hostjson-file):

[image]